# watchdog daemon is not active after reboot in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, watchdog

The command `sudo systemctl status watchdog` shows it is "dead". The command `sudo systemctl enable watchdog` didn't helps. The command `sudo systemctl start watchdog` starts it (and it works), but only until reboot.

```
$ cat /etc/default/watchdog 
# Start watchdog at boot time? 0 or 1
run_watchdog=1
# Start wd_keepalive after stopping watchdog? 0 or 1
run_wd_keepalive=1
# Load module before starting watchdog
watchdog_module="none"
# Specify additional watchdog options here (see manpage).
```

Comment: See, and perhaps add to, [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/watchdog/+bug/1535854).

Answer (score 1):

File `/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service` has no [Install] section. Workaround by copying it into `/etc/systemd/system` and modifying as needed.

Comment: this has not been fixed yet as of Jan 2018.